# unable to import pcl to python?

Tags: python-2.7

I followed the instructions given here http://www.pointclouds.org/downloads/linux.html .
After installing the libpcl , what should be done to import it in python?

Comment: is there an error message when you simply add `import pcl` to the headsection of your file?

Answer (score 1):

You should import libpcl now in your Python script. Follow this [Link](http://www.pointclouds.org/news/2013/02/07/python-bindings-for-the-point-cloud-library/). 
According to the link I assume `import pcl` would do the trick.